# Is Redis connection shared in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

In my Rails app I have an initializer that creates a Redis connection:

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379, :db => 3)
```

My question is: is this connection shared for all workers for this app, or does each worker thread create its own connection everytime I use $redis?

Comment: which rack server are you using? unicorn, mongrel, passenger, ...? unicorn for example uses different processes as workers, not threads, so the connection is not shared

Comment: I am using Unicorn. If I use Passenger, how would I create connection pools for Redis?

Answer (score 5):

You can try using gem `connection_pool`, which is generic pool for any network client.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'connection_pool'
```

initializers/redis.rb:

```
require 'connection_pool'

conf = YAML.load(File.read(File.join('config','redis.yml')))
redis_config = conf[Rails.env.to_s]

Redis.current = ConnectionPool.new(size: 10, timeout: 5) do 
  Redis.new host: redis_config['host'], port: redis_config['port'], db: redis_config['db']
end
```

config/redis.yml

```
development:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
  db: 0
test:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
  db: 15
production:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
  db: 0
```

Then later, in your code:

```
Redis.current.with do |conn|
  value = conn.get('foo')
  conn.sadd('bar', 1)
end
```

Inside the `with` block, `conn` will contains a Redis object from the pool. It will be returned to the pool when the block exits, either normally or because an exception was thrown.

Comment: how to use the ConnectionPool in my application ?

Comment: @dzpqzb just use the `Redis.current` object, e.g.: `Redis.current.sadd('foo', 1)`

Comment: @Tombart not quite, `Redis.current` is the `ConnectionPool` object, you have to call its `with` method to get the individual Redis object.

Comment: Are you able to expand on "Then later, in your code"? I'm currently trying to use Redis for caching, queueing (with Resque) and ActionCable and would like to set up connection pooling but am unsure of where to put that code. Thanks.

Comment: @Marklar Probably in your model (or anywhere where you want to access Redis). The code inside block, variable `conn` represents one connection to Redis database. After exiting the block connection is returned back to the pool for other instances to re-use it.

Comment: @Marklar Did you find the way to use Redis+connection_pool and Action Cable?

Comment: @Marklar: I think you have to be careful here, as using Resque will start up a separate process to the one replying to http requests (normally rack server). Therefore, when setting up the connection pool you should be careful not to have 2 pools of 10 connections each. Unless that's intended.